# Excel VBA: Tell the print setup somehow which row = end of first page?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables in my spreadsheet (one on top of the other separated by a couple rows), call them T1 and T2. T1 is dynamic in terms of how many rows it contains, T2 is static. I can easily find out which row T1 ends on and then add 1 to it or so -- call this variable T1EndRow.

I want to code it so it'll know that everything from row 1 to T1EndRow will be on the first page of the print preview. T2 will flow over to the second page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `HPageBreaks` and `VPageBreaks` members of the `Sheet` object to set the location of horizontal and vertical page breaks.

For instance if T1EndRow is a named range in the last row that you want to appear on page 1, go:

```
Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = ActiveSheet.Range("T1EndRow")
```

If T1EndRow is a `Long`, try:

```
Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = ActiveSheet.Cells(T1EndRow, 1)
```

Strangely, Excel is throwing errors on this line (which is the only way to adjust the page breaks) unless you are in xlPageBreakPreview mode:

```
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
Set Sheet1.HPageBreaks(1).Location = Sheet1.Cells(58, 1)
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
```

I also noticed that it throws a different error if the `.Location` you set is outside of the `UsedRange` of the sheet, so you might want to make sure that requirement is already met.

Comment: Hm for some reason this is throwing errors for me, but it may be because I am referring to my workbook/sheet via reference objects. For instance, right now I am trying Set xlWBk.Sheets(1).HPageBreaks(1).Location = xlWBk.Sheets(1).Cells(T1EndRow, 1) ... is there something else I might need to reference? Is ActiveSheet a requirement? I didn't state this in the question so I will accept the answer either way -- thank you!

Comment: @IAmBatman Aah, well this is something I hadn't considered. Apparently you need to be in xlPageBreakPreview mode for this to work, brutal... Updating answer.

Comment: I figured out one way to insert the break by doing xlWBk.Sheets(1).HPageBreaks.Add Before:=xlWBk.Sheets(1).Range("A" & T1EndRow+1) but then the table headers from the prior page leak onto the second page for some reason.

Comment: @IAmBatman Yeah I was avoiding `HPageBreaks.Add()` because often what that does is if your page break was at 50, and the next is at 100, and you want to move the first one to 65, you'll end up with 3 pages, from 1-50, 51-65, and 66-100 :/ Maybe something like that is going on now?

Comment: In this case, the report is always generated from scratch and will be two pages long (thus only one page break) with T1 scaled to first page and everything else in T2 being on the second. Is there a way to force headers to not repeat on the second page?

Comment: Got it:  With xlWBk.Sheets(1).PageSetup via things like .PrintTitleRows = "" and .PrintTitleColumns = ""

Comment: I see that now in the PageSetup options. Good catch.